# how to solve this setTime out in javascript with an if condition?

Tags: php, javascript

here's my script , it's a combined php and javascript

```
<?php
$countdown = strtotime("22:00") - time();
$itemtime = "22:00";
$realtime = substr(date('H:i'),0,5);
?>

<script>
var itemtime = "$itemtime";
var countdown = '$countdown';
var url = "$redirectpage";
var realtime = "$realtime";

// HOW WILL I ADD AN IF STATEMENT WITH THE SETTIMEOUT FUNCTION
// WHEREBY, if(realtime == itemtime) ..that's the only time the 
// redirection should occur

setTimeout(function(){
 location.href='$redirectpage'; 
    },countdown * 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: You should compute the `countdown` clientside.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$countdown = strtotime("22:00") - time();
$itemtime = "22:00";
$realtime = substr(date('H:i'),0,5);
?>

<script>
var itemtime = "<?php echo $itemtime;?>";
var countdown = '<?php echo $countdown;?>';
var url = "$redirectpage";
var realtime = "<?php echo $realtime;?>";

// HOW WILL I ADD AN IF STATEMENT WITH THE SETTIMEOUT FUNCTION
// WHEREBY, if(realtime == itemtime) ..that's the only time the 
// redirection should occur

setTimeout(function(){
 if(realtime == itemtime) location.href='$redirectpage'; 
},countdown * 1000);
</script>
```

Assuming `$redirectpage` is set in JavaScript and not PHP. If it is set in PHP, you'll need to assign it as I did above.

Comment: You forgot about last `$redirectpage`.

Comment: @hsz - see the note at the end.

Comment: i have tried this before `setTimeout(function(){
 if(realtime == itemtime) location.href='$redirectpage'; 
},countdown * 1000);` but it didn't work at all

Comment: @sasori - And what happened? Did you get errors? This should work unless there's more code you're not mentioning.

Comment: it did not redirect at all

Comment: Where does `$redirectpage` come from?

Comment: there's no error in console of firebug at all...it just doesn't redirect when i placed that if statement inside the setTimeout function...i wonder if that's the right way to do it

Comment: Yes, the login is fine, provided the variables you set in PHP are what you think they are. Have you tried increasing the duration in the setTimeout call from 1000 to say 5000 to see if it's a timing issue?

Comment: no,it's not a timing issue,,,because if it's setTimeout function alone without the if statment,it redirects the page ....but with the if statement , it doesn't

Comment: So then you need to make sure `realtime` and `itemtime` are actually equal. Have you tried logging or alerting `realtime`?

Comment: they are actually equal..how did i know?..because i echoed them to display on the page

Comment: Could there be any extra spaces in the values that would cause them to not be equal?

Comment: no,there's no spaces at all nor extra values..any other ideas how to solve this thing ?

Comment: One last thing, did you try changing `var url = "$redirectpage";` to `var url = "<?php echo $redirectpage";?>';`

Comment: yes i did, it's the same thing...actually the location.href doesn't have problems at all, it's the if statement only when being added at inside the setTimeout function

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with my own solution,i place this inside the setTimeout function

```
if(countdown < 0) setTimeout("location.reload(true);",1000); location.href= "$redirectpage";
```